# RJ45 Connector - Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, connector, rj45, lan

I need an STM32F4 to communicate through LAN.
An electronics technician provided a schematic (Version 1), of which I'm only showing the relevant part.
I did my own research on the Internet and in the datasheets of both the transceiver and the connector and sent him another version (Version 2) and asked for his feedback.

He replied that the 10pF capacitors between RX+/RX-/... and ground should stay, same thing for the 4700pF capacitors between ground and earth, and that pin 8 of the RJ45 connector should not be connected to earth but rather to ground.

I couldn't find any reference to this usage of capacitors, neither in the documentation or on the Internet.

Since I'm not an expert at all, I wondered if someone had enough experience with it and could explain what I should do !?

Please, correct me if I'm wrong.
Thank you in advance for your response.

This is the hardware that I'm using :

- The transceiver : https://export.farnell.com/microchip/lan8742a-cz/trx-10-100-ethernet-rmii-sqfn/dp/2373286
- The RJ45 Connector/Transformer : https://export.farnell.com/wurth-elektronik/74990101210/jack-modular-rj45-1port-8p8c/dp/2356129?ost=74990101210
- The STM32F4 : https://export.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/stm32f429bit6/mcu-32bit-cortex-m4-180mhz-lqfp/dp/2469581?ost=stm32f429bit6

[image: RJ45 Connector - Version 1 & 2]

Comment: please do not link to sales pages ... link to the datasheets at the manufacturer's website

Comment: So you did not ask the designer why the things were connected like that? Maybe the designer could have pointed you to a document which says they must be there?

Comment: He sent a screenshot of the datasheet of the transceiver but it was completely unrelated. I checked the same datasheet myself and there was no mention of the capacitors. Besides, Microchip provides schematics of how things should and I just reproduced them as-is but he disagreed.